# Music URI null pointer exception in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

Greeting all
I had been passed over several days over and still can't solve the problem, null pointer

> exception error on setting music URI "var musicTrack =
> ContentUris.withAppendedId(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,curSong!!)"

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VZyr7.png)

```
 fun PlaySong(){
    mp!!.reset()
    var song = songlist?.get(songPosition!!)
    var curSong = song?.Id


    var musicTrack = ContentUris.withAppendedId(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,curSong!!)
    try {
        mp!!.setDataSource(applicationContext,musicTrack!!)
    }catch (e: Exception){
        Log.e("Music Service","Error On Setting Data Source",e)
    }
    mp!!.prepareAsync()
}
```

Comment: Most likely `curSong` is null. Asserting it is non-null will cause an exception if it is.

Comment: Still not working bro

Answer (score 0):

The stack trace is saying it's line 78 where the problem is happening. `mp` is probably null and you're trying to call a method on it, at a guess.

Using `!!` is a bad sign because it means that value could be null, but you're not handling that possibility and saying "trust me, it's never going to be null". That usually doesn't work out! I know this from experience...

Either make `mp` a non-nullable type if you know it's never going to be null, otherwise you need to null-check it before you do anything with it. Never use `!!` (the rare times you actually do need it, you'll know you need it and it's an exception to the rule)

Comment: Now null point is Ok but mp is just Mediaplayer class and just declareed as global parameter and also under onCreate view mehtod var mp = MediaPlayer; the problem is not calling method , just setting URI  , there is not calling method in my mentioned codes buy the way this was working in Java , this issue is on Kotlin oncreating another app, pls check it again

Comment: Run it again with your current code, look at the stack trace and find the line that says ``Caused by kotlin.KotlinNullPointerException``, look at the line below that where it says ``MainActivity.PlaySong(MainActivity.kt:LINE_NUMBER)`` and post the code on that line number in your ``MainActivity`` file (if you're using Android Studio, ctrl+G will let you jump to a line number)